# How to fix 'The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]' on docker compose?

Tags: mysql, docker, phpmyadmin, docker-compose

I'm setting up a wamp. The docker-compose was working very well until I experience some problems with the phpmyadmin and mysql container. I couldn't connect nor from php or phpmyadmin and usually had this error message : `mysqli_real_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]`

I was able to solve the problem by just connecting entering the shell of the db container `docker exec -it db mysql -uroot -p` and running this command : `ALTER USER 'root' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password by '123456';` But this kind of boring because I have a partner working on the same project and we have to change working posts a lot so it means rerun docker each time in the development phase so I was wondering what's wrong on my docker-compose...

Here it is :

```
version: "3.1"
services:
    www:
        build: .
        container_name: app
        ports: 
            - "8001:80"
        volumes:
            - ~/Desktop/WORK_in_progress/camagru/www/:/var/www/html/
        links:
            - db
        networks:
            - default
    db:
        image: mysql:8.0
        container_name: db
        restart: always
        tty: true
        ports: 
            - "3306:3306"
        command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
        command: --innodb-use-native-aio=0
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: CAMAGRU
            MYSQL_USER: user
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: 123456
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456 
        volumes:
            - ~/Desktop/WORK_in_progress/camagru/dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
            - ~/Desktop/WORK_in_progress/camagru/conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d
            - persistent:/var/lib/mysql
        networks:
            - default
    phpmyadmin:
        container_name: phpmyadmin
        restart: always
        tty: true
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        links: 
            - db:db
        ports:
            - 8000:80
        environment:
            MYSQL_USER: user
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: 123456
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456
volumes:
    persistent:
```

note : I don't use any configurations file, I modified a bit a compose that I found online.

Answer (score 2):

Your command is right, the issue appears because you have defined the `command` key two times, and the second one is overriding the first one. Instead you should define it only once and like this:
`command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password --innodb-use-native-aio=0`